# Why onDestroy recreates the Fragments when Activity recreate after process killed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm trying to understand what happens to `Fragments` when `Activity` recreates after process gets killed and `Activity destroy`.

Scenario : I have an application with multiple activities and first activity loads configuration and used by other activities. On low memory when application on background ,the process gets killed . 
After the process killed if i select the application (from recent apps) , the activity is recreating. But the current activity when recreates will try to access the configuration and app crashes.

So , i decided to finish the activity if configuration not loaded on activity recreate , and navigate to first activity which loads the configuration. 
This resolves most of the problems , but if the Activity has fragment and when `onDestroy` happens on recreate , the app crashes as the `onDestroy` is trying to recreate the fragments.

```
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1120)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchReallyStop(FragmentManager.java:1956)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onReallyStop(FragmentActivity.java:790)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.doReallyStop(FragmentActivity.java:767)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:314)
```

I tried to remove the fragments in `onDestory` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to save the Configuration in onPause() method, and reload it when activity recreate.

Comment: Yes this can be done. But my configuration loading process is too big and its hard to persist all the information.